# limit the number of objects returned in a has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, limit, has-many

How can I limit the number of rows returned in a has many relationship? For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end
```

I want to be able to do:

```
User.includes(:photos => {:limit => 8}).all
```

This obviously doesnt work, but something with this functionality. Do I need to write out the SQL myself?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I dont want to limit the association, just the query results. So a User might have a thousand photos, I only want the top 3 returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a limit option to the has_many association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :limit => 8
end
```

**EDIT**

According to your needs:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :all_photos, :class_name => "Photo"
  has_many :photos, :limit => 8
end
```

*note: changed 'class' to 'class_name' in the all_photos association*

Comment: It DOES limit the rows returned. However you could just select the 8 top results from the has_many association -> "@user.photos[0..7]"

Comment: I want to be able to do this using eager loading, that way I can pull up the top 1000 records with only the first 3 associations in each model...

Comment: So you should create two associations. One for the whole collection and an other one for a limited collection. I edited my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work with eager loading, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6722104/217956

Answer (score 12):

You don't have to hard code the limit in the model.  You can call `@user.photos.limit(8)`.  You can also call `@user.photos.scoped` to get a scope object that does lazy loading.  The thing returned from `@user.photos` may look very, very much like an `Array`, but it's not - it lies to you!

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy for an interesting trip into the rabbit hole - the thing you get back is delegating pretty much all of the standard object inspection calls (`class`, `singleton_class`, `methods`, `method`, etc.) to an `Array` object, but it's delegating a certain set of calls to an `ActiveRecord::Associations::*` object.  That's why if you call `@user.photos.method(:<<)` it will tell you it's using `#<Method: Array#<<>`, but it's not actually using that - it's using the one in `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`!

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `:limit` on the actual `has_many` declaration.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :limit => 8
end
```

Comment: How do I do this on a per query basis instead of on the model?