# Rails 3 Limiting Included Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, eager-loading

For example I have a blog object, and that blog has many posts. I want to do eager loading of say the first blog object and include say the first 10 posts of it. Currently I would do `@blogs = Blog.limit(4)` and then in the view use `@blogs.posts.limit(10)`. I am pretty sure there is a better way to do this via an include such as `Blog.include(:posts).limit(:posts=>10)`. Is it just not possible to limit the number of included objects, or am I missing something basic here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076392/limit-the-number-of-objects-returned-in-a-has-many

Comment: Odd, I can't even get this approach to work in the Rails(3.1) console. added `has_many :recent_posts, :class_name => 'Post', :limit => 3`. But when I do `Blog.includes(:posts).first` I still got all the posts not just the first 3.

Comment: Try Blog.includes(:recent_posts).first.recent_posts

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work for me either. The limit is not applied to the query for posts. Odd.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you can't apply a limit to `:has_many` when eager loading associations for multiple records.

Example:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :limit => 5
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
end
```

This works fine for limiting the number of posts for a single blog:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :010 > Blog.first.posts
  Blog Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `blogs`.* FROM `blogs` LIMIT 1
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`blog_id` = 1 LIMIT 5
```

However, if you try to load all blogs and eager load the posts with them:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 > Blog.includes(:posts)
  Blog Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `blogs`.* FROM `blogs` 
  Post Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`blog_id` IN (1, 2)
```

Note that there's no limit on the second query, and there couldn't be - it would limit the number of posts returned to 5 across all blogs, which is not at all what you want.

EDIT:

A look at the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) confirms this. You always find these things the minute you've figured them out :)

> If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it
>   will be ignored, returning all the associated objects

Comment: So what to do in this case then?

Answer (score 2):

You need to limit the number of posts in your blog model like this:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :included_posts, :class_name => 'Post', :limit => 10
    has_many :posts
end
```

So then you can do:

```
$ Blog.first.included_posts.count
=> 10
$ Blog.first.posts.count 
=> 999
```

Comment: But wouldn't that limit the total number of posts per blog?

Comment: Right, but you can create multiple has many associations. See code.

Comment: I see how that works, but is it possible to also get the blog object back within the query? `@blogs = Blog.limit(3).recent_posts` actually gives me an array of Posts, but not the initial parent Blog. I'm trying to optimize my db/query usage if that makes any sense.

Comment: `blog = Blog.find(3).include(:included_posts)`